# Magento Observer Save Attribute If Not Exists

Tags: php, magento

I created an observer to save selected multiselect attribute values in a separate table.Attribute value should save only if not exists.Here is my code

```
public function catalogProductSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product=$observer->getProduct();
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $makeOptions=$_product->getAttributeText('make'); //array  [0] => Audi [1] => BMW
    $partsfindermodel=Mage::getModel('partsfinder/parts');
    foreach($makeOptions as $makeOption)
    {
        if(!$partsfindermodel->getMake($makeOption))
        {
            $partsfindermodel->setMake($makeOption)->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Only the last element in the array getting saved in table.

How to save values if not exists?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to consider getting the model by attribute - e.g. part number - and, if it loads you will have an ID. If there is no entry already then you won't get an ID. Therefore, when it comes to save, it should work.

Another gotcha is that you can add to the model with more fields in the database but sometimes they do not work - unless you run the install script again. So you may want to try this after removing the table and the entry in core_resource for the setup of your module. Then, on an initial install all the tables get made in the backend and magically work properly with online forms.